# What did Agnetha say to Colin Gunderson in "I can get you Frigg"?

Tags: the-almighty-johnsons

In S1E08 of *The Almighty Johnsons*, Agnetha goes to Colin Gunderson's house to ally herself with him regarding his daughter.  At first, there's no indication that he'll see her, but then she [says something](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2095704/Norse.m4a) (MPEG4 link to the speech in question) and he lets her in.

I assume the language was Old Norse.  Did she just repeat her previous words, but by using the language hint that she had knowledge of Gunderson's secret?  Did she explicitly reveal that she was a goddess herself?  Did she say anything about his daughter?

Answer (score 1):

Agnetha leads off with "Someone who has a common interest" in English, followed by her speech in Old Norse.  The speech is decidedly longer than her English phrase, so it is more than just a simple translation.  Given the polite conversation Colin and Agnetha have after her being invited in, I assume it was not divulging herself as a goddess straight off (that would have given away too much too easily, knowing Agnetha).  Instead I think she would have said something implying that she knew more which, along with it being spoken in Old Norse, was enough to get her entrance.

I don't know any Old Norse, nor does the Internet apparently.